# How do you get an integer number for an item in group in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, count

I have two tables in a SQL Server 2008 database, one listing groups and another mapping those groups to records for objects. One group may have many objects.

I've got the following query

```
SELECT GroupNumber
From dbo.Groups G
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Mapping_ObjectToGroup m ON G.GroupID = m.GroupID
```

Which results in a table like

```
GroupNumber
700
700
700
701
701
702
703
703
```

How can I get a second column that would give me an indexing number for each group like this:

```
GroupNumber | Ctr
700 | 1
700 | 2
700 | 3
701 | 1
701 | 2
702 | 1
703 | 1
703 | 2
```

Essentially I'd like to be able to have an integer represent each item within a group. Is there a name for what I'm doing? Can anyone help me do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` for this.  Do you have a field to establish an `order by`?  If not, you can randomly select with null.  Here's an example:

```
SELECT GroupNumber,
     row_number() over (partition by GroupNumber order by (select null)) ctr
From dbo.Groups G
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Mapping_ObjectToGroup m ON G.GroupID = m.GroupID
```

Comment: Could one just use `ORDER BY newid()`?